# Result rows duplicated by spider engine

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sharding, spider

I've two mysql server 'G0' and 'G1'. And there is a one row test table on them respectively.

G0:

```
mysql> select * from test.t1;
+----+--------+
| id | node   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | DB-G0  |
+----+--------+
1 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

G1:

```
mysql> select * from test.t1;
+----+--------+
| id | node   |
+----+--------+
|  2 | DB-G1  |
+----+--------+
1 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm then using the spider engine offered by MariaDB 10.4 (`mysqld  Ver 10.4.12-MariaDB-1:10.4.12+maria~bionic-log for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 (mariadb.org binary distribution)`) to combine them like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
   id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
   node TEXT
) ENGINE=Spider
COMMENT='wrapper "mysql"'
PARTITION BY HASH (id) (
 PARTITION par0 COMMENT = 'srv "G0", tbl "t1"',
 PARTITION par1 COMMENT = 'srv "G1", tbl "t1"'
);
```

It's working well for a simple query like this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select * from test.t1;
+-----+--------+
| id  | node   |
+-----+--------+
|   1 | DB-G0  |
|   2 | DB-G1  |
+-----+--------+
2 rows in set (0.013 sec)
```

But it doubled the results when using this condition:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select * from test.t1 where id != 0;
+-----+--------+
| id  | node   |
+-----+--------+
|   1 | DB-G0  |
|   2 | DB-G1  |
|   1 | DB-G0  |
|   2 | DB-G1  |
+-----+--------+
4 rows in set (0.017 sec)
```

Here is my Spider related settings:

```
#
# * Spider
#
spider_bulk_update_mode      = 2
spider_bulk_update_size      = 512K
spider_bulk_size             = 512K
spider_conn_wait_timeout     = 5
spider_connect_timeout       = 3
spider_direct_dup_insert     = 1
spider_direct_order_limit    = 1
spider_multi_split_read      = 1
spider_net_read_timeout      = 5
spider_net_write_timeout     = 5
spider_quick_mode            = 3
spider_quick_page_size       = 1000
spider_remote_trx_isolation  = 1
spider_support_xa            = 0

spider_remote_time_zone        = +00:00
spider_remote_access_charset   = utf8mb4
spider_remote_autocommit       = 1
spider_remote_default_database = 0

spider_general_log          = 1
spider_internal_sql_log_off = 0
spider_log_result_errors    = 4
```

I commented out all the above settings and tried again, the results are same.
Is there something wrong with me or it is a bug?

Comment: `PARTITION BY HASH (id)` looks odd. [KB examples](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/spider-storage-engine-overview/) are all `PARTITION BY KEY(id)`. Rather than populating G0, G1 manually, insert directly into the spider engine and observe the tables on both.

Comment: Hi @danblack I've changed the `PARTITION BY HASH (id)` to `PARTITION BY KEY(id)`. And the result is exactly same, the duplicated rows still there.

Comment: and the other suggestion?

Comment: I created a new issue for it: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-22246